# NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription supplied in info.plist but apple still asks for one

Tags: ios, privacy, info.plist

In my first upload from Xcode 8 to iTunes Store I received the following message from Apple

> This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.
>
> This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NSCameraUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

I researched and then added the following entries to my info.plist

[image]

I then uploaded a new build to the iTunes store but have received the same warning email again.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

I've added the Media Library Usage description (as suggested by Dan Clark below)

[image]

but apple have again rejected the build and replied with the exact same warning email.

Comment: My app doesn't require photo access, but Apple's system still is griping that I need the photo access string. This is likely a bug on their end. :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well, it turns out that the info.plist that I was editing in Xcode's left file list was not the plist that Xcode was referencing under identities. It was referencing an info.plist from a backup folder.

So there was never a problem with the usage description keys.

Answer (score 1):

Click on the "show the find navigator" icon near the top left of the screen.

Type in the search bar "info.plist"

Click on "TrackerTest/info.plist

Go to "Info"

Add the specified target to iOS target properties.

Such as Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description, with a string.

Answer (score 0):

There's also a Media Library Usage description entry that you'll need to add to the PList.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Isn't media library for music?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are updating the correct info.plist file in your project folder , as there are few different info.plist files in the project (Test, UITest...)